# Loading file with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Here is the function I'm using:

```
jOWL.load("owldoc.owl", function(){});
```

jOWL.load takes in an owl document as a parameter (as seen above). I have 3 of these documents on the server, and would like the user to be able to chose which document to load by pressing a button.

I wonder if it is possible to have a string 'owldoc.owl', 'owldoc2.owl', or 'owldoc3.owl' passed to a javascript variable, which could then be passed in as a parameter to jOWL.load

How would I go about this?

Comment: Like... passing a parameter to the document via the load function?

Comment: hopefully, i've never used the load function before, thanks for the pointer

Comment: thank you all, the responses are perfect :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the function below using `onclick='loadFile("1"); return false;'` inside of the respective link.

i.e.:

```
    <a href="" id='load1'>Load 1</a>
    <a href="" id='load2'>Load 2</a>
    <a href="" id='load3'>Load 3</a>
```

function:

```
    function loadFile(param){
        jOWL.load("owldoc"+param+".owl", function(){});
    }
```

To have onclicks that do not show up in line, the easiest way is to add ids to the anchors and call this function on page load using `manageOnclicks();`:

```
    function manageOnclicks(){
        document.getElementById('load1').onclick = function(){loadFile('1'); return false;}
        document.getElementById('load2').onclick = function(){loadFile('2'); return false;}
        document.getElementById('load3').onclick = function(){loadFile('3'); return false;}
    }
```

Comment: I like this, although I'd like it better to get the onclick out of the inline html and bind the loadFile function to the click event of each anchor element.

Answer (score 1):

Sample HTML

```
<input type='button' onclick="loadFile('owldoc.owl')" value='Load Owldoc'/>
<input type='button' onclick="loadFile('owldoc2.owl')" value='Load Owldoc2'/>
<input type='button' onclick="loadFile('owldoc3.owl')" value='Load Owldoc3'/>
```

Javascript

```
function loadFile(fileName) {
    // filename contains the variable
    // you can now do        
    //jOWL.load(filename, function(){}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

HTML:

```
<h3>Choose a file to load</h3>
<ul id='choose_file'>
    <li><a data-file='1'>File 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-file='2'>File 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-file='3'>File 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#choose_file').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        var file_to_load = evt.target.getAttribute('data-file');
        jOWL.load('owldoc'+file_to_load+'.owl', function() {
            /* callback code here */
        });
    }, false);
}, false);
```